# How to access the database using DB Facades?

Tags: php, eloquent

Per [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database) we can do something like this to run a raw query :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);
```

But I couldn't find a way in the documentation to initialize eloquent with my database in order to execute that query.

I'm using PHP 7.3 (no frameworks) to work with eloquent. Where can I initialize the database to eloquent?

I've found in the doc ways to do so using the [`\Capsule\Manager`](https://github.com/illuminate/database) as seen in the readme in this link, but no way to use this while getting the `Db::select` to work, any idea on how to properly configure this?

I'm looking for something like this maybe ?

```
DB::init([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => ''
])
```

Comment: Did you try this
 DB:statement(select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);

Comment: @DevRamesh the problem is not the query, it's how to connect eloquent to the database using `DB::`

Comment: What do you mean by "no frameworks"? You're are using Laravel, right?

Comment: @TravisBritz no, the tag is just to say that it's laravel's eloquent. I'm integrating illuminate database using composer on a pure PHP code. No frameworks means I'm not using any framework, thus I'm not using laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another way to use raw queries using the capsule manager directly :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

$capsule = new DB;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => DB_SERVER,
    'database' => DB_DATABASE,
    'username' => DB_SERVER_USERNAME,
    'password' => DB_SERVER_PASSWORD,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    ]);
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$test = DB::select('select * from products where products_id = :id', ['id' => 19536]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have written the wrong syntax for eloquent

> select method is for the select column name of the table in now days

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

or use

```
db::raw('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the problem is not with the select as I mentionned, but with how to get a connection going with the database.

Comment: @GiveMeFreedomOrGiveMeFire this will help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-illuminate-database-with-eloquent-in-your-php-app-without-laravel--cms-27247